# Set up a distribution in LogLikelihood that depends on data

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting

I want to define a loglikelihood function to perform a fit of some data points to a function, like the following, but using the native LogLikelihood[] function.

$
likelihood=\sum_{i}(Log{(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2*\pi*}*\sigma_i}\cdot e^{-\frac{(y_i-f(x_i))^2}{2\sigma_i^2}})})
$

where the function f depends also on the parameters I want to estimate by maximization.

If the $\sigma_i$ are constant I can create the loglikelihood in this way (e.g. using $\sigma=0.2$):

```
likelihood = LogLikelihood[NormalDistribution[0, 0.2], ydata - f[xdata]];
```

But if the $\sigma_i$ of the normal distribution are given by the experimental data, they can be different for each data point and I don't if it is possible to set a different distribution parameter for each data point

Obviously, creating the LogL "by hand" with the explicit PDF expression works perfectly, but I saw that if the LogL function is defined using the native function of Mathematica, the computation time is much lower, so I'd like to know if there is a way to solve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `NonlinearModelFit` example with weights (and I'm assuming that the $\sigma_i$ values are known), one can use the `LogLikelihood` function in the following manner:

```
data = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {3, 2}, {5, 4}};
σ = data[[All, 1]] + 1;

logL = LogLikelihood[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 
  (data[[All, 2]] - Log[a + b data[[All, 1]]^2])/σ];
```

In other words you use a `Normal[0, 1]` distribution and divide the difference between the observed value and the model value by the standard deviation.

Maximizing the log of the likelihood results in

```
FindMaximum[{logL1, a > 0 && b > 0}, {{a, 2.3}, {b, 0.4}}]
(* {-3.84479, {a -> 2.23705, b -> 0.435855}} *)
```

This gets you the same estimates of the parameters as using `NonlinearModelFit` with weights:

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, Log[a + b x^2], {a, b}, x, Weights -> 1/σ^2];
nlm["BestFitParameters"]
(* {a -> 2.23705, b -> 0.435855} *)
```

**Something more general**

Suppose your data consists of `{x, σ, y}`:

```
data = {{0, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 0}, {3, 4, 2}, {5, 6, 4}};
```

You can use `Inner` to essentially "vectorize" the `LogLikelihood` function:

```
logL = Inner[LogLikelihood[#, {#2}] &, 
  NormalDistribution[a + b #[[1]]^2, #[[2]]] & /@ data, 
  {#[[3]]} & /@ data, Plus][[1]]
(* -(1/2) (-1 + a)^2 - 1/8 (a + b)^2 - 1/32 (-2 + a + 9 b)^2 - 
   1/72 (-4 + a + 25 b)^2 - Log[2] - Log[4] - Log[6] + 2 (-Log[2] - Log[π]) *)
```

And there are probably cleaner ways to use `Inner`.  But a brute-force sum of log likelihoods seems just about as fast and more straightforward:

```
logL = Sum[LogLikelihood[NormalDistribution[a + b data[[i, 1]]^2, data[[i, 2]]],
  {data[[i, 3]]}], {i, Length[data]}];]
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I haven't thought to normalize the residual and use a NormalDistribution[0,1].

Comment: But is there a more general way to do it? This could be a non-standard case, but if I want to use for example a Poisson distribution I can't use this method

Comment: Editing your question to include that need would get you more targeted help.

Comment: @Andrea  I added something a bit more general.  And, of course, if your function is linear, then `GeneralizedLinearModelFit` should be considered.  And if your error structure consists of an additive normal distribution, then `NonlinearModelFit` with weights might be the way to go.